# Is there a way I can resolve this deep learning errors as I am just starting to apply deep learning on my dataset

Tags: r

Please can someone help me on how to resolve this problem. This is my first time of using deep Learning and I am stuck because I don't know what to do again.

```
`> # compile the loss function
 > model %>% compile(loss= "categorical_crossentropy", 
+                   optimizer="adam",
+                   metrics="accuracy")
> #fit model
> history <- model %>% fit(training,
+                          trainLabels,
+                          epochs=100,
+                          batch_size=32,
+                          validation_split=0.2)
```

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: in user code:

```
C:\Users\VICOMA\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
C:\Users\VICOMA\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
C:\Users\VICOMA\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
C:\Users\VICOMA\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\VICOMA\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:531 train_s 

 I tried to use this line of code **tensorflow::tf$compat$v1$disable_eager_execution()** as someone 
 suggested but the error I am getting is this -

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: Calling `Model.fit` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was 
constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call ` 
Model.fit` with eager mode enabled.
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the error by entering the correct input_shape. I t was an oversight on my side